# Python 3.5 pip install kivy, unable to find vcvarsall.bat eventhough visual studio is installed

Tags: python, windows, kivy

I have been trying to install kivy for Python 3.5 on windows 10.

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install Cython
pip install kivy
```

On this last one, i retrieved following error message

```
    running build_ext
Build configuration is:
 * use_rpi = 0
 * use_mali = 0
 * use_egl = 0
 * use_opengl_es2 = 0
 * use_opengl_debug = 0
 * use_glew = 1
 * use_sdl2 = 0
 * use_ios = 0
 * use_mesagl = 0
 * use_x11 = 0
 * use_gstreamer = 0
 * use_avfoundation = 0
 * use_osx_frameworks = 0
 * debug_gl = 0
 * debug = False
Detected compiler is msvc
cythoning C:\Users\Silas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4wc0y9s5\kivy\kivy\graphics/c_opengl_debug.pyx to C:\Users\Silas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4wc0y9s5\kivy\kivy\graphics\c_opengl_debug.c
building 'kivy.graphics.c_opengl_debug' extension
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

----------------------------------------
```

Command:

> "c:\users\silas\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Silas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4wc0y9s5\kivy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\Silas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-696he5pr-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Silas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4wc0y9s5\kivy\

`

Eventhough I Installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, after first encountering the problem.

How can I resolve this Problem ?

Comment: Modify the installation of Visual Studio and remember to check `C++` to be installed

Comment: how am i supposed to modify the installation, isnt c++ installed by default with visual studio ?

Comment: I don't think so. run the setup again and choose to modify

Comment: Check if `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` exists on your system. If yes, it should be just a path thing. And just a note, `pip install kivy`(for current version `1.9.1`) **WON'T** compile on Python 3.5 and higher, you need to get the latest code i.e. master branch from github. Or, install from already compiled [nightly wheels](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#nightly-wheel-installation)

Comment: No, the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC exists, but it only contains more folders and no vcvarsall.bat file, for your later 2 options i will still need the vcvarsall.bat file though right?